# Shifting arrays in F#

Tags: arrays, f#

So I have a function which shifts some ternary values in an array by the desired amount, but when I shift any array, (b) value(s) (on the right if shifting left, and the left if shifting right) will always be replaced with null. Here's my code:

```
let ( <<| ) (a:FalseTrit[]) (b:int) =
    array.Copy(a, b, a, 0, a.Length - 1)
    array.Clear(a, a.Length - b, b)
let ( |>> ) (a:FalseTrit[]) (b:int) =
    array.Copy(a, 0, a, b, a.Length - b)
    array.Clear(a, 0, b)
```

I couldn't find any answers on the internet. Is there a better way to do this, or something I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the comment by [Alexey Romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov) why you should prefer standard library functions from `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Array` module over instance members of `System.Array`: Type inference makes them easier to use and curried arguments prettier.

While the documentation for [`Array.blit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.blit%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) misses the assurance of [`System.Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy) in regard of arrays overlapping, I strongly suspect the same applies because of its underlying implementation:

> If *sourceArray* and *destinationArray* overlap, this method behaves as if
>   the original values of *sourceArray* were preserved in a temporary
>   location before *destinationArray* is overwritten.

```
let (<<|) a b =
    Array.blit a b a 0 (Array.length a - b)
    Array.fill a (Array.length a - b) b Unchecked.defaultof<_>
// val ( <<| ) : a:'a [] -> b:int -> unit
let (|>>) a b =
    Array.blit a 0 a b (Array.length a - b)
    Array.fill a 0 b Unchecked.defaultof<_>
// val ( |>> ) : a:'a [] -> b:int -> unit
```

Here, the behavior of the original code is kept: `Unchecked.defaultof` will return `null` for reference types.

On a stylistic note, consider replacing the code by a generator expression returning a fresh array, because mutation is not seen as functional best practice, and neither are custom operators returning `unit`.

```
let (<<|) a b = [|
    for i in b..Array.length a - 1 + b ->
        if i < Array.length a then a.[i]
        else Unchecked.defaultof<_> |]
// val ( <<| ) : a:'a [] -> b:int -> 'a []
let (|>>) a b = [|
    for i in -b..Array.length a - 1 - b ->
        if i < 0 then Unchecked.defaultof<_>
        else a.[i] |]
// val ( |>> ) : a:'a [] -> b:int -> 'a []
```

Answer (score 2):

`Array.Clear` sets a range of elements in an array to the *default* value of each element type (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clear?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

Since `FalseTrit` is a reference type and not a value type, it has default value `null`.

Comment: It would be good to point to `Array.Fill` which should be used instead.